# Vaadin: Pass value from main page to window page

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, vaadin

I am new to Vaadin 7, currently am facing problem with Pass value from main page to window page.

When I click a event in Main page, It will open a Window page, here i need to get value from main page. based on that value I have to control logic in Window page.Here sample code,what I have tried. I want to send "beNumber" parameter value to window page.

```
pan[beNumber].addClickListener(new MouseEvents.ClickListener() {

                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                        @Override
                        public void click(MouseEvents.ClickEvent event) {

                                    // Create a sub-window and set the content
                            Window subWindow = new Window("Patient Transfer", new WardMovementView());
                             subWindow.setCaptionAsHtml(true);
                             subWindow.setModal(true);
                             subWindow.setWidth("1200px");
                             subWindow.setHeight("800px");
                           UI.getCurrent().addWindow(subWindow);

                         }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you reuse the beNumber at other places.
Either you expose a getBENumber() method in your main class and then retrieve it from the sub windows.

The other way would be to subclass Window and have a method where you can set the beNumber from externally.

Like this:

```
pan[beNumber].addClickListener(new MouseEvents.ClickListener() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void click(MouseEvents.ClickEvent event) {

        // Create a sub-window and set the content
        Window subWindow = new PatientTranfserWindow("Patient Transfer", new WardMovementView());
        subWindow.setCaptionAsHtml(true);
        subWindow.setModal(true);
        subWindow.setWidth("1200px");
        subWindow.setHeight("800px");
        subWindow.setBENumber(beNumber);
        UI.getCurrent().addWindow(subWindow);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass non final variable dont use anonymous class. Simplest solution is to create Class that implements MouseEvents.ClickListener and pass that value to the constructor. That gives you ability to reuse it.

It should look like this.

```
pan[beNumber].addClickListener(new    MyCustomListener(beNumber));

class MyCustomListener implements MouseEvents.ClickListener{

final int beNumber;//I guess you use int in your arrays

public MyCustomListener(int beNumber){
this.beNumber = beNumber;
}
@Override
 public void click(MouseEvents.ClickEvent event) {

                                // Create a sub-window and set the content
                        Window subWindow = new Window("Patient Transfer", new WardMovementView(beNumber));//pass that var to your custom component if you want to use it
                         subWindow.setCaptionAsHtml(true);
                         subWindow.setModal(true);
                         subWindow.setWidth("1200px");
                         subWindow.setHeight("800px");
                       UI.getCurrent().addWindow(subWindow);

                     }


}
```

This aproach is also very usefull if you want to use it in multiple places.